# In proving that $\sqrt{a}$ is always irrational, $\forall a\in\left\{\Bbb R^+ : 1< a\neq b^2\right\}$... a different way.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

I was trying to prove the following statement: $$\sqrt{a}\text{ is always irrational, }\forall a\in\left\{\mathbb{R}^+ : 1<a\neq b^2\right\}.\tag{$b\in\mathbb{Z}$}$$ I know there is at least one other post of this, but I have not looked at it because I already know how to prove this (using the *Fundamental Theorm of Algebra*, or FTOA). However, I wanted to come up with my own proof, instead of using a well-known proof. Below is what I came up with. I have used *proof by contradiction* (or in latin, *reductio ad absurdum*). May somebody  verify whether or not it is true?

---

**Supposed Proof:**

*Proof*: Assume the statement otherwise, then $$\exists p, q\in\left\{\mathbb{R}^+ : \sqrt{a}=\frac{p}{q}\Leftrightarrow aq^2=p^2\right\}.\tag{$q\neq 1$}$$ Since $a\neq 1$ then $p\neq q$, and either $p>q$ or $p<q$. Consider the former, i.e. $p > q$. Subtract $q^2$ from both sides. $$\begin{align} aq^2 - q^2 &= p^2 - q^2 \\ \Leftrightarrow q^2(a-1) &= (p+q)(p-q) \\ \Leftrightarrow a - 1&{\ \mid} \ \ (p+q)(p-q) \\ \Leftrightarrow a &\equiv 1\pmod {p\pm q}.\end{align}$$ For the last statement, it is unknown whether $a-1\mid p+q$ and $a-1\nmid p-q$ or vice versa, but what *is* known, is that $a-1$ divides one of those factors.

Since there are infinitely many primes $s$, then there are infinitely many numbers $s_0$ such that $s-1=s_0$. By Fermat's Little Theorem, raising both sides of the congruence to the power of $s-1$ yields that the modulo is prime, i.e. $$a^{s-1}\equiv 1^{s-1}= 1\pmod {p\pm q},$$ thus $p+q$ and/or $p-q$ is prime. If we were to assume that the fraction $p/q$ was irreducible, then $\gcd(p,q)=1$, making it perfectly allowable for one of the conjugates to be prime. However, $$\begin{align} q^2(a-1)&=(p+q)(p-q) \\ \Leftrightarrow q^2&{ \ \mid} \ \ (p+q)(p-q) \\ \Leftrightarrow q&{ \ \mid} \ \ p\pm q.\end{align}$$ This is of course a contradiction, because now $q\mid p$, therefore $\gcd(p,q)\neq 1$; therefore $p/q$ can be simplified; and therefore $p\pm q$ is not prime, unless $p=0$. But that means $\sqrt{a} = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow a = 0 < 1$, even though $1 < a$. Contradiction.

Because of this contradiction, the first case cannot be true, i.e. $p\not > q$. Therefore, the only case left is that $p<q$. But, using the same steps, since $p < q$, then $p - q < 0$. $$\therefore \exists t\in\mathbb{R}^+ : q^2(a-1) = -t(p+q)(p-q).\tag{$p,q>0$}$$ But $q^2\nmid -t$ because otherwise $\sqrt{-1}\mid q$ or $-1\mid q$, and thus either way, $q\notin\mathbb{R}^+$.

And $a-1\nmid -t$ because if $1 < a$, then $a - 1 > 0 > -t$. And, trivially, $t\neq 0$, for otherwise $q^2 = 0$ $\Leftrightarrow q = 0$ and $ a = 1$. Contradiction.

Thus our second case cannot be true either, and since both of our two cases lead to a contradiction, then it is false to assume the statement otherwise. This completes the proof. $\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\,\,\,\Box$

**Edit:** As noted in the comments, $a\neq 2$, but I can prove seperately that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, so $a\neq 2$.

---

If my proof is correct, how can I prove the same statement but with the condition that $a\in (0,1)$? I want to prove that in the same fashion. This post is entirely derived from my curiosity.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your quantifiers are unclear.  What sort of thing is $b$ meant to be?   You are making a statement about a specific $a$ but then you refer to "$\forall a$".  Parallel questions for $p,q$.

Comment: @lulu sorry if I am a bit sloppy. $b$ is real and the only thing specific on $a$ is that $a > 1$.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are trying to prove.

Comment: If $b$ is real, then $b^{2}$ is an arbitrary non-negative integer, so if $a \ne b^{2}$, the only choice is to have $a < 0$.

Comment: Moreover divisibility takes a trivial form among real numbers.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti $b$ is a positive real number -- oh wait, hahah woops. I will make $b$ an integer

Comment: Try writing out what you want in words.  Don't introduce variables without declaring whatever assumptions you are making about them.

Comment: How is the fact that $a-1$ divides, say $p+q$ means it is $1 \text{ mod } p+q$?

Comment: @Yanko I meant it is either $1\text{ mod } (p+q)$ or $1\text{ mod } (p-q)$.

Comment: @Yanko because if $a\equiv b\pmod c$ then $a - b\mid c$

Comment: That's wrong... if $a=2$ then $1$ divides whatever you want but $2= 2 \text{ mod } (p\pm q)$ because $p\pm q$ is always even.

Comment: No it's the opposite, if $a = b \text{ mod } c$ then $c|a-b$.

Comment: @Yanko ahhh yes... I will include that.

Comment: @Yanko are you sure about the mod statement??

Comment: Moreover, you appear to claim that if $a-1$ divides $(p+q)(p-q)$, then it has to divide one of the factors, and this is generally untrue.

Comment: if $a = b \text{ mod } c$ that means that $a=ck +b$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and therefore $c|a-b$.

Comment: @Yanko ok. I think I was confused.... sorry for wasting your time with this ridiculous post.

Comment: @user477343 No worries, mistakes are the best way to learn.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Yes, I see now. Because what if $p+q$ has another divisor, or $p-q$ has a divisor? Thank you for that note. I will definitely think a bit differently from now on :)

Comment: @user477343 if 'a' is real, then shouldn't 'b' be rational instead of integers? Counter-example:$\sqrt{2.25}=1.5$

Comment: @abc... I was specifically proving that $\sqrt{a}$ *is not an integer* if $a\neq b^2$. I guess you might be correct, then, as $\sqrt{a}$ is irrational if it is not an integer.

Comment: But $\sqrt{a}$ is not necessarily irrational if it is not an integer.

Comment: @abc... I was incorrect because I misunderstood the definition of modulo. My entire proof was just a bunch of mumbo jumbo... a *fake proof* **Edit:** Yes true, ok, but I was proving for only the integers. I shouldn't get confused with how all integers are rational, but not all rationals are integers